# Ctypes: Error in Returning struct pointer and accessing its elements

Tags: python, c, ctypes

So I have the following C struct below:

```
struct Matrix {
    int ncol;
    int nrow;
    double **mat;
};
typedef struct Matrix Matrix; // can do Matrix *myMat; instead of struct Matrix *myMat;
```

I have the following Python object to store it below:

```
import ctypes
library = ctypes.CDLL(r"C:myDirectory\NumLib.so")
def MATRIX(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('ncol', ctypes.c_int),
                ('nrow', ctypes.c_int),
                ('mat', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)))]
```

I have a C function (`calculator_matrix`) that returns a pointer to a Matrix struct,

```
Matrix* calculator_matrix() {
    return parseReturn_getMatrix(ret, 1); // irrelevant function
}
```

to which I call in Python by:

```
library.calculator_matrix.argtypes = []
library.calculator_matrix.restype = MATRIX
```

where `library` is my shared library. The problem is that all my C functions work locally in C, meaning `calculator_matrix()` returns a Matrix* when called in a C file, but when I call the function in Python it returns `None`

```
mat = library.calculator_matrix()
print(mat) # this just prints None
```

This should be working just fine, as it works in a local C file by itself but when I implement it into Python it does not seem to translate the correct type. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

## Side Note

So some have suggested using `library.calculator_matrix.restype = POINTER(MATRIX)` instead of `library.calculator_matrix.restype = MATRIX` , but I get the following error: `TypeError: must be a ctypes type` making it seem that the MATRIX object in Python isn't a ctypes type, to which it should be.

I've noticed that most ctypes tutorials included `ctypes.Structure` for their Python C struct container but I get the following error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` when I use

`def Matrix(ctypes.Structure)`
so that is why I used def `Matrix(Structure)` instead. I think that may be the problem why I get the `TypeError: must be a ctypes type` on the suggestion

```
library.calculator_matrix.restype = POINTER(MATRIX)
```

## Update

The issue was that there was typo of declaring MATRIX() as def instead of class, see selected answer below for a good way to declare and access elements of a ctypes struct

Comment: `library.calculator_matrix.restype = ctypes.POINTER(MATRIX)`

Comment: @CristiFati, I did that and get the following error TypeError: must be a ctypes type

Comment: `class MATRIX(ctypes.Structure):` as well.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, see SIDE NOTE of my question, just ran into that

Comment: `class` not `def`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen this is what happens when you try to learn python in a couple of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.restype` is wrong and the `MATRIX` is is declared wrong.  Here's a minimal reproducible example.

**test.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Matrix {
    int ncol;
    int nrow;
    double **mat;
} Matrix;

__declspec(dllexport)
Matrix* calculator_matrix() {
    Matrix* p = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    p->ncol = 2;
    p->nrow = 2;
    p->mat = malloc(2 * sizeof(double*));
    p->mat[0] = malloc(2 * sizeof(double));
    p->mat[1] = malloc(2 * sizeof(double));
    p->mat[0][0] = 1;
    p->mat[0][1] = 2;
    p->mat[1][0] = 3;
    p->mat[1][1] = 4;
    return p;
}
```

**test.py**

```
import ctypes

class MATRIX(ctypes.Structure): # fix here
    _fields_ = [('ncol', ctypes.c_int),
                ('nrow', ctypes.c_int),
                ('mat', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)))]

library = ctypes.CDLL('./test')
library.calculator_matrix.argtypes = ()
library.calculator_matrix.restype = ctypes.POINTER(MATRIX) # fix here

mat = library.calculator_matrix().contents
print(mat.ncol,mat.nrow)
print(mat.mat[0][0],mat.mat[0][1])
print(mat.mat[1][0],mat.mat[1][1])
```

Output:

```
2 2
1.0 2.0
3.0 4.0
```